# Replace special string characters in jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, string

HI,

I have some string from XML file, and I I want to replace all "**& lt;**, and **& gt;**" ... in "**<** and '**>**"

this is the AJAX call (jQuery):

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "xml.xml",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(xml) {


            alert(xml);

            $(xml).find('reslult').each(function(){
                            var bid = $(this).find('bid').text();
                            $('.Sign2').text(bid);
            });
            }
        });
```

I can't use "DataType:XML", because XML file is beginning with  .....  :(

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alexander,
You can use two string replace functions before your $(xml)... line, like so:

```
xml.replace(/& lt;/g,'<');
xml.replace(/& gt;/g,'>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use the javascript unescape() function on the string?

Comment: no, thats not for encode/decode special html characters, its for uri characters...for example, a space " " escapes to "%20"